# flutter : unable to get a specific index or selection go to another page

Tags: flutter, indexing

can you correct me on my code,

i am trying to let flutter know that i need him to go to a different screen if listindex 5 is selected which is letter E, what happens with my code is that all selection goes to the screen where it says why you select letter E, instead of the other page which is thank you for selecting

[this is the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY3f8.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQMGU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 30 of your code, you write :

```
if (index < 5) {
```

But in Dart, an array start from the index 0 and not 1.
Your array has a 5 element list. [0,1,2,3,4]

You should write :

```
if (index < 4) {
```

Comment: ***facepalm i realized that the way it works is 0,1,2,3,4 not 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

The index starts at 0.
Fix from

```
if (index < 5) {
```

to

```
if (index < 4) {
```